# Write protecting a page in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to write protect a certain memory location on an ARM SoC. If possible, the whole page which would contain the memory location. I am aware of mprotect, but I am not looking for something from userspace. The aim is to implement a wrapper function to access that memory location after temporarily removing the write protection and once the write is completed, the protection is activated again. Other drivers will be using this wrapper function. There is pte_modify() which takes a pte_t. I have the physical address and I can get the pfn. Is there a way to get pte from pfn? Are they same?

Is there a way to do this? There is no userspace involved and remap_pfn_range() like functions are not needed, I guess.

Comment: Just curious on why you'd want to create such a wrapper? It sounds like a X Y problem to me.

Comment: Some drivers intentionally access it, some others access the same location unintentionally and ends up resetting the system. My aim is to mainly know who accessed it and cause a fault when an unintentional access occurs.

Comment: Sounds like a driver conflict of some sort. You could certainly implement this but I would just solve the driver conflict so it doesn't happen in the first place.

Comment: Why I am planning to implement this is because it would be easy to detect accidental writes and driver conflicts looking at the call stack if there can be a panic or oops when this happens. Just preparing for the worst.

Comment: Here is what I tried,
`my_pfn =  __phys_to_pfn(phys_addr);
my_pte = pfn_pte(my_pfn, PAGE_KERNEL);

pte_wrprotect(my_pte);

pte_mkwrite(my_pte);` And in between I tried writing the physical address directly using a pointer and it writes without any issue. Also pte_write() macro says it is still writable.

Comment: If a driver conflict is occurring and its corrupting the device state, I would think the driver isn't correctly requesting the memory region it uses. Linux normally won't let two drivers use the same memory region. Otherwise, insert asserts into the driver so it panics when it detects an inconsistency.

Comment: It is not actually driver conflict. Probably just some runaway pointers.